# shell multiline selection from word to character

Tags: regex, bash, awk, multiline

.textexpandrc

```
[yoro] よろしくお願いします。
[ohayo] おはようございます。
元気ですか？
[otsu] お疲れさまでします。
```

Looking for

```
$ KEY=ohayo; awk "???"  ~/.textexpandrc 
おはようございます。
元気ですか？
```

awk or sed is fine, but I'd like to avoid using a mix of awk/sed/perl/tr/cut etc because I'm under the impression that awk is robust enough to handle this on its own.

The best I could find on my own was

```
$ KEY=ohayo; awk "/\[${KEY}/,/\[otsu/"  ~/.textexpandrc | sed "s/\[${KEY}\] //" | grep -v otsu
おはようございます。
元気ですか？
```

But I need to know the next key in advance (not impossible but ugly). Strangely, if asking awk to search until the square bracket, it fails to select a multiline

```
$ KEY=ohayo; awk "/\[${KEY}/,/\[/"  ~/.textexpandrc                                      
[ohayo] おはようございます。
```

Currently using a single-line parser solution as follow

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CONFIG=${HOME}/.textexpandrc
ALL_KEYS=$(sed 's/\].*/]/' ${CONFIG} | tr -d '[]')
KEY=$(echo $ALL_KEYS | rofi -sep ' ' -dmenu -p "autocomplete")

grep "\[${KEY}\]" $CONFIG | sed "s/\[${KEY}\] //" | xsel -ib  # ← HERE
xdotool key ctrl+shift+v
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set up the `RS` and `FS` variables to match `[` and `]`, this works quite well:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="\["; FS="\] " };  $1 ~ key { print $2 }' key=ohayo tmp.txt
```

You pass in the parameter you're searching for using `key=....` on the command line instead of setting a variable. This makes it much easier to write the awk script within single quotes.